# Need to retain dropdown list value in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I'm using time_tracker_simple module in Drupal. When someone selects from the drop down list and hits submit it stays on the same page but the value is not retain. How can I retain the values for the drop down list when selected.

Below is the code used in the module.

```
  function time_tracker_simple_timer_form($form_state) {
  global $user;
  $active_timer = _time_tracker_simple_get_timer();
  //*** Both start and start buttons must actually be on the form for #submit to work correctly
  $form['stop'] = array(
    '#value' => t('Stop'),
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#weight' => 20,
    '#access' => FALSE,
    '#button_type' => 'timer_control_stop',
    '#submit' => array('time_tracker_simple_timer_stop'),
  );
  $form['start'] = array(
    '#value' => t('Start'),
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#access' => FALSE,
    '#weight' => 20,
    '#submit' => array('time_tracker_simple_timer_start'),
    '#button_type' => 'timer_control_start',
  );-----This part is the drop down list------
  $activities = array();
  $activities[] = '(none)';
  $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {time_tracker_activity} ORDER BY weight ASC");
  while ($result = db_fetch_object($results)) {
    $activities[$result->taid] = $result->name;
  }
  if (count($activities) > 1) {
    // The activity choser
    $form['activity'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Activity'),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#weight' => 5,
      '#options' => $activities,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the drupal form api allows you to pass a default value to the form item like this:

```
$form['activity'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Activity'),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#weight' => 5,
      '#options' => $activities,
      '#default_value' => $form_state['post']['activity']
    );
```

Comment: I try attributes along with some java script but that doesn't retain the values. There's two buttons in this module one is Start the other is Stop. When someone selects from the drop down list and clicks on Start it submits but stays on the same page with a new button which is Stop, But it's not retaining the selected value that the user selected. and in the url it goes to /node when someone clicks on the Start button.

Comment: Setting the default value to a `$form_state` value is redundant, if

Comment: "stays on the same page but the value is not retain." - I agree Clive, but that's what he asked for;)

Comment: Tech: You need to save the submitted value some place.. there is extensive [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/751826) about building forms properly in drupal, even how to validate and handle the submitted data, try some of that